# php notices of Undefined Variable & Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Am learning & executing php by working on Joomla project
How to Improve this code & resolve the PHP Notices - Any suggestions - solutions - well appreciated !!

**Notice**: Undefined variable: cond in*/home/mygames/public_html/components/com_toys/models/category.php on line 140
(which is $sql line)*

```
   function loadSubCat($id,$Carmodel,$minprice,$maxprice){
   $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
   $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
   $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
   global $Itemid;  
   if($Carmodel!="")
   $cond=" and prod_id='$Carmodel' ";
   $sql = "Select * from #__toycar_products Where prod_cat_id='".$id."' $cond and prod_status='1' and prod_id in (select v_prod_id from #__toycar_variants)  Order By prod_sorder";
```

**Notice**: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/truecar7/public_html/components/com_toys/models/category.php on line 200

Line 200 is  return $row->id;

```
   function getItemIdByName($Name){
   $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication();
   $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
   $database =& JFactory::getDBO();
   $sql = "Select id  from #__menu Where name = '".$Name."'";
   $database->setQuery($sql);
   $row = $database->loadObject();
   return $row->id;
}
```

**Edit**

Hello Lodder & Elin, it works but like this, else it's showing undefined variable notice for row on return $row line.

```
function getItemIdByName($Name){
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')
 ->from('#__menu')      
 ->where('id = ' . $db->quote($Name));      
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ($rows as $row){
    $row = $row->msg;
     }    
$row='';
return $row;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Don't use special characters like `#` in table names to avoid such problems `#__menu`

Comment: @VahidHallaji - This is how Joomla database table are designed. It's a prefix

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing with the return of $row given that you have hard coded it to an empty string.
If you just want to return one string for one row you should not be doing $db->loadObjectList()  which is giving you an array of objects. Instead load the result you want .. don't select '*' select 'msg' and just return $db->loadResult()  http://docs.joomla.org/JDatabase/loadResult

Comment: Thanks Elin, works Awesome !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following. I have made some changes to your function and used Joomla 2.5 coding standards for the database query.

```
$Name = "XXXXXXXXX";  //define the name variable

function getItemIdByName($Name){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('*')
     ->from('#__menu')      
     ->where('id = ' . $db->quote($Name));      
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $row = $row->msg;
    }
    return $row;
}

echo getItemIdByName($Name); //echo the result of the function
```

Comment: Thanks, however after executing the page is showing error - Notice: Undefined variable: database in on line 

Fatal error: Call to a member function loadObjectList() on a non-object on line

Comment: ahh sorry. change `$database->loadObjectList();` to `$db->loadObjectList();`

Comment: Yep done, however - it now shows new notices - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line

Notice: Undefined variable: row on line

Comment: You need to use $db->quote($Name)  not $Name (assuming you want to match the string).    Are you trying to return a list or one row? You should be sure to use the appropriate return type.

Comment: @RuchikaModi - Please see my updated answer. I have tested the code and it works. I've also used `$db->quote($Name)` as pointed out by Elin

Comment: Thanks, it works with slight modification. Have added the modification in edit, could you pl advise if correct.

Comment: @RuchikaModi - The `return` should go after the `foreach` loop

Comment: Ok done, but its then showing - Notice: Undefined variable: row in line with return $row. If i modiy the edit by definining empty string then its going on fine

Answer (score 2):

For your `Undefined Notice`, You have to modify your codes like this

```
$cond = '';
if($Carmodel!="") {
   $cond = " and prod_id='$Carmodel' ";
}
```

For `Trying to get property of non-object` Notice : I think `$row` is empty that is why throws notice.Check `$row`

```
var_dump($row);
```

**Problem :**

```
$database->loadObject(); // This line
```

Comment: Thanks. But, after Implementing its rather now showing Notice: Undefined variable: cond on line. Also, for second part shall i remove the line of $database->loadobject(). pl advise

Comment: Hello, I think i made an error as your solution to undefined variable works perfectly. Thanks !!